# Calculating the n-th moment of a RV, including negative fractional moments

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, moments, moment-generating-function

I am stuck trying to solve the following exercise..

Let $X: \Omega\to [a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ be a uniformly distributed random variable. Compute the n-th moment of $X$, i.e. compute $\mathbb E[X^n]$ for any $n > −1.$ (note that you should also include negative fractional moments!

The fact that n can be smaller than 0 is making it very difficult for me to understand what I am supposed to do.. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can work this out by evaluating the integral directly.
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f_X(x)dx = 
\int_{a}^{b} x^n \frac{1}{b-a}dx = \ldots
$$
As long as the interval $[a,b]$ does not include 0, you won't have an issue.

Can you see why we need $n>-1$?

Comment: I don't find it so clear why we need n > -1.. Care to explain?

Comment: Sorry - that was a bit cryptic! I meant can you see why it's $n>-1$ instead of $n \geq -1$.

Comment: That remark is indeed cryptic. When $a\lt 0,$ $X^n$ isn't even defined for most $n\lt 0.$  When $b\lt 0$ or $a\gt 0,$ this integral is finite for *all* $n$ for which $X^n$ can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

- find out the distribution of $X$
- find out how to compute expectation values $E[\cdots]$ with anything on the dots.

Put these together.